# Bitbucket: Merge works but with error: "unable to merge branch" "wasn't merged into master"

Tags: bitbucket, git-merge

I'm getting an error whenever I merge from a branch into my master branch in Bitbucket. "Unable to merge branch - [branch_name] wasn't merged into master". What is strange is that when I then go and look at the master branch's source code following the supposedly failed merge, it *does* have the code that could only have come from the merge. This is actually happening on all of my repositories and on all branches during merge. So it's clearly not a conflict. I'm not sure if I should just trust that it's working and the error is bogus or fix something.   I'm using the "merge commit" strategy if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there has been a merge, try an [list your "feature branches"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-unmerged-branches-389778602.html)

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/files/304578655/598940223/2/1504193450412/commitpage-withbranchgraph-sidexpand.png]

Those are the branches that BitBucket Cloud consider as "unmerged branches": you can verify if BitBucket still consider some of your branches as unmerged.